# How do I calculate for what values of **H** are the solutions of the differential equation periodic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

Given the differential system
$$\dot{x}=p$$

$$\dot{p}=-x^3+x$$

and

$$H(x,p)=\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$$

How do I calculate for what values of **H** are the solutions of the differential equation periodic?

Comment: This is typical Hamiltonian equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(control_theory)). I imagine you have had a lecture on the subject. Right ? Tell us where are you blocked.

Answer (score 1):

The trajectories of the system correspond to level curves of the Hamiltonian. Closed curves that do not contain the stationary points ($(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,0)$) are periodic solutions. Rewrite the Hamiltonian as
$$
H(x,p)=\frac14(x^2-1)^2+\frac12\,p^2+\frac14,
$$
making it clear that level curves are bounded. When $H=1/4$ we get the stationary points $(\pm1,0)$; when $H=1/2$ the point $(0,0)$ and two homoclinic orbits joining $(0,0)$ to itself, one going around $(1,0)$ and the other around $(-1,0)$. Can you do the rest now?

[image]

The level curves $H=E$ can be drawn from the equation
$$p=\pm\sqrt{2\,E-\frac12-\frac12(x^2-1)^2}$$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer at all. Why is $(0,0)$ going around $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$? How can I know that? Obviosuly I can't do the rest. Please can you write more detailed answer.

Comment: Draw the lines $H(x,p)=c$. Look at the picture.

Comment: How to draw that without program? I still don't understand what are here perodical solutions? Are those resting points of my equation or what?

Comment: That is something you must have learned in your course: closed level curves mean periodic orbits. I have edited the answer to explain how to get the level curves.

Comment: Okay. I have learned that closed level curves mean periodic orbits. But how do I get what for what values of H are the solutions of the differential equation periodic? What is the meaning of p that you have written?

Comment: The level curves are $H(x,p)=E$; solve por $p$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: But what values of E and x should I put in that equation?

Comment: You should try all real values, and draw the corresponding graph. Yo see immediately that $E\ge1/4$ is necessary. Start form $E=1/4$, let $E$ grow and see how the graph changes.

Comment: And when I put values how do I see from there what is periodic?

Comment: Please draw the graphs. When they form a closed curve, you have periodic solutions.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get closed curve...